# What is this difference while copying files?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I am using Windows 7. I tried to copy five (movie) files to my Sandisk pen drive. It took 10 minutes to finish, when i was copying them individually.

When I selected the same five files as a group and then copied them to another folder of my pen drive, it took me only 5 mins.

Note that the file 's size is same each of 500 MB.

Why is this difference?

Comment: can you repeat that experiment when starting from a fresh booted windows? as in .. boot fresh, select indivdually, measure time, reboot, select as group, measure time?

Comment: @akira i installed windows7 last month and havent installed any software except ms office,and i m having ddr3 ram with amd x2 proceessor does hardware make diffrence?

Comment: i didnt ask about hw, i asked about repeating the experiment without reusing the OS-filecache (which triggers as soon as you work on files).

Comment: @akira i tried with fresh installation at my friend's system with same hardware configuration it took me 7mins for individuals and for group it took me about 4mins,i also noted that if i add individual files the time shown for first windows is 2mins &transfer rate is 2mb/sec,and for 2nd file estimated time 5mins &1mb/sec

Comment: i didnt say "fresh installation" either. just reboot the system to flush away the systems IO-cache ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx ). you might measure the speed of really reading the files vs getting the files from the cache (aka "ram"). also: try to measure it the other way around: first group the files, then transfer individually. also: do you batch the the individual files so the copy process runs in sequence or is the copying done in parallel (as in: you just drop the files onto the pen and 5 copy-actions are in progress at the same time)?

Comment: copy process done in sequence sir

Comment: so, what are the results of your redone benchmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to memory resources allocation. For 5 movies (2GB total), a 2 GB file swap is created; but for 1 movie (400MB) * 5 it has to created and then delete file swaps. Add additional CPU priorities.

A better way to copy would be to use TeraCopy or Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier, which bypasses the operating system and use DMA Channel (direct memory access method). Note: This  applies to USB1.1/2.0 only. USB3.0 is way too fast, but no USB pen drives available (atleast for now - Aug 2012)

Comment: any references to backup your claim that a "swap" file is created? i am also interested in a reference for that "terracopy uses dma" which makes it faster on windows7 than the built-in file-copy-mechanism (which i tend to believe is bogus)?

Comment: @C2940680: Huh? It's August 2012 and you're saying there are no USB 3.0 pen drives available? Also, I'd love to see some hard figures about the TeraCopy/Roadkil Copier vs. Windows copy speeds as well.

Comment: i am using usb 2.0 ,if we clean the temp memory will it be fast before copying..?i like to mention i noted in my bios usb port transfer speed to hispeed